# How many combinations from the alphabet given certain rules

Tags: combinations

Looking for a way to calculate the number of combinations of letters in the alphabet with the following restrictions:

1. any number of letters in a combination
2. no repeat letters (as in a single entry can contain one A, but not two As)
3. If a set of letters contains letters that are not adjacent, it must also contain all letters between those letters.

It's that third rule that I don't have a clue how to get around.

Comment: Well, numbering the letters from least to greatest (so $A=a_1$ and $Z=a_{26}$ if you are using the standard English alphabet), we see that your string must be a permutation of $\{a_n,a_{n+1},\cdots,a_{n+k}\}$ for some $n,k$ so...

Comment: Note: if by "combination" you mean that the order is not relevant, then the problem is much, much simpler since you aren't concerned about the permutations of the set I mentioned.